# Multiple WS call in one action, how to handle Promise objects in java play framework?

Tags: java, web-services, playframework-2.2

I develop a little server in PlayFramework2/Java which has to retrieve data from multiple WS (REST/JSON), manipulate the data from theses WS, then compose and return a result.

I know how to call one WS, manipulate the data and return response. But I don't know how how to call successively several web-services, handle the data between every call and generate an aggregated answer.

Please help.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use F.Promise.sequence for combining two or more responses. Try the below code**

```
 public static Promise<Result> selectFeed() {

      F.Promise<WS.Response> response1 = WS.url(<firstUrl>).get();
      F.Promise<WS.Response> response2 = WS.url(<SecondUrl>).get();
      F.Promise<List<WS.Response>> responses = F.Promise.sequence(response1, response2);

     F.Promise<Result> resultPromise= responses.map(new F.Function<List<WS.Response>,Result>()     {

            @Override
            public Result apply(List<WS.Response>  o) throws Throwable {

                //some code;
                String s= o.get(0).asJson().toString();


                String s2 = o.get(1).asJson().toString();
                return ok(s+s2);
            }
        });

    return resultPromise;
   }
```